# Prolog traverse list for adjacent positions

Tags: list, prolog, conditional-statements

I'm programming a pacman AI (yes it's homework), however I'm fairly new and I want to find all the adjacent positions (up, down, left and right) to pacman's current position. Now I have a list of all positions that are free in the level but I want to remove all those that aren't adjacent to the current position. Here's my adjacent rules:

```
adjacent((X,Y), (Xx,Yy)) :-
    X+1=Xx,
    Y=Yy.
adjacent((X,Y), (Xx,Yy)) :-
    X-1=Xx,
    Y=Yy.
adjacent((X,Y), (Xx,Yy)) :-
    X=Xx,
    Y+1=Yy. 
adjacent((X,Y), (Xx,Yy)) :-
    X=Xx
    Y-1=Yy.
```

Now I want to use a list of positions (Xx,Yy) and only use the positions that fulfill one of the adjacent rules.
So I have to traverse the list, use adjacent (Prolog will check all 4 rules, correct?) and if true, add them to a new list.

So something like this

```
    find_adjacent((X,Y),[(Xx,Yy)|T], Z] :-
        adjacent((X,Y),(Xx,Yy) -> add_to_new_list((Xx,Yy),Z);
```

Is this the correct way of thinking in Prolog? Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: A common mistake in Prolog is to confuse the operator for unification `=/2` as some kind of expression equality operator. So expressions like `X+1 = Xx` doesn't do what you think. It will try to unify the term `'+'(X,1)` with `Xx`. It won't evaluate `X+1`. For equality of evaluation, you'd use `=:=/2`, but it does require that expressions on both sides be fully instantiated. If you want to assign the value of an expression, you'd use `is/2`. For example, `Y is (X * 2) mod 7.` For `is/2`, the right hand side must have all instantiated variables, and the left is a single variable.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Prolog without constraints, you will have to normalize/evaluate the expression first. That is:

```
adjacent((X,Y), (Xx,Yy)) :-
   Xx is X+1,
   Yy = Y.
...
```

Even simpler and faster would be

```
adjacent((X,Y), (X, Yy)) :-
   ( Yy is Y+1 ; Yy is Y-1 ).
adjacent((X,Y), (Xx, Y)) :-
   ( Xx is X+1 ; Xx is X-1).
```

And if the second argument is always ground (no variables):

```
adjacent((X,Y), (Xx, Yy)) :-
   abs(X-XX)+abs(Y-Yy) =:= 1.
```

You might consider using `library(clpfd)` which would permit you to state all four rules just as compactly as above version, but still would permit variables everywhere.

```
adjacent((X,Y), (Xx, Yy)) :-
   abs(X-Xx)+abs(Y-Yy) #= 1.
```

However, as a beginner, there are better examples getting acquainted with `library(clpfd)`.

Comment: Yeah I don't want to overcomplicate. I'll just use the 4 rules, as long as prolog, for each position (Xx,Yy) checks all 4. I don't understand though why X+1=Xx why replaced with Xx is X+1. Are they the same?

Comment: @UserConscious: No they are different, see my first sentence. You have to evaluate `X+1`. With `(is)/2` or `(=:=)/2` as shown.

Comment: Ok, understood. Could I also use, in the first case, member((X+1,Y),[(Xx,Yy)|T]? Will it evaluate X+1?

Comment: @UserConsious: No, as said, you can only evaluate with `(is)/2` or `(=:=)/2` and some other comparison operations

Comment: Prolog can be very confusing. Thanks.

Comment: @UserConscious a "term" in Prolog such as `X+1` isn't evaluated every time it appears because Prolog manages terms as-is since the programmer may very well want to manipulate it as a term, not an evaluated expression. For example, if you were writing predicates to do algebraic manipulation or differentiation, you don't want Prolog trying to actually compute values. So, in Prolog, there are only certain operators that will evaluate arithmetic expressions. That being `is/2` (for assingment), `=:=/2` for evaluated equality, etc. Operators like `=/2` are for *unification*.